# How to declare empty string in Metro UI XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to write simple replacement for missing in WinRT DataTriggers, something like:

```
<dt:DataTrigger Property="Message" Value="">
    <dt:Setter TargetName="tbMessage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</dt:DataTrigger>
```

So I have class DataTrigger with property Value that is set in XAML. I need to set Value to string.Empty. When I use "" (empty braces) Value is set to null, not to string.Empty. 
I have tried to define in Resources empty string:

```
<x:String x:Key="EmptyString"></x:String>
```

And use it like

```
<dt:DataTrigger Property="Message" Value="{StaticResource EmptyString}">
    <dt:Setter TargetName="tbMessage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</dt:DataTrigger>
```

Value still is set null. Also I have tried to use next code:

```
xmlns:sys="using:System" ... <sys:String x:Key="EmptyString"></sys:String>
```

This code throws exception "An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: The type 'String' was not found."

Approach with using `<x:Static Member="sys:String.Empty" />` can't be used because in WinRT `x:Static` missing.

Is it even possible to declare an empty string in WinRT XAML?

Comment: Have you tried using ="{x:Null}" ?

Comment: Yes, then my Value property is set to null as expected, but I need empty string :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static System:String.Empty}" Name="emptyString"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately x:Static present only in WPF, not in WinRT.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check in Win8. And if you try to change trigger like   '<dt:DataTrigger Property="Message.Length" Value="0">
    <dt:Setter TargetName="tbMessage" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</dt:DataTrigger>' ?

Comment: Yes, in this particular case using Message.Length solves my problem. But there are two things why I can't use it:

Comment: The only alternative I can think of - make {Binding} extension and solve your problem through it.

Comment: Yes, in my case using Message.Length solves problem. But there are two things why I can't use it: 1. Message can be set to null, so Length can be not accessible; 2. In DataTrigger code I subscribing to OnPropertyChanged if DataTrigger's owner implements INotifyPropertyChanged so I can track changes of Message and apply Setters, but string (owner type of Length property) don't implement this interface; Currently I've fixed my issue by checking if property's type is string and Value is null and if so - I'm replacing null value with string.Empty, but as for me such code little bit smells :)

Comment: I have tried to use Binding but this class is much more useless in WinRT than in native WPF.